# Difference between clip.to_videofile and clip.write_videofile

Tags: python, video, numpy, ffmpeg

what is the difference between `clip.to_videofile` and `clip.write_videofile`?

Do they have any effect on the frames of a CompositeVideoClip?

i wrote a code:

```
video=CompositeVideoClip([clip1,clip2.set_start(dur)] 
video.write_videofile("video.mp4",fps=clip1.fps) # or video.to_videofile("video.mp4",fps=clip1.fps)
clip=VideoFileClip("video.mp4")
video.save_frame("frame1.png")
clip.save_frame("frame2.png") 
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
im1=Image.open("frame1.png")
image1=np.asarray(im1)
im2=Image.open("frame2.png")
image2=np.asarray(im2)
```

when i compared the two arrays image1 and image2, they were not the same...Can anyone explain me why does this happen? and what do i do if i have keep the frame from getting changed when i write a composite clip into a video?

Comment: Can you provide any more context, like where these classes come from?

Comment: @tcaswell i have used the module moviepy for VideoFileClip, ImageClip, CompositeVideoClip, save_frame...PIL for Image and numpy for np.asarray